# How to create a custom login for sfGuard user in Symfony?

Tags: php, symfony1, sfguard

I am using Symfony 1.4 and ORM as Propel in my project. I have configured the Settings.yml to secure my page. But can i make a custom login/logout by my action extending all the SfGuard plugins functionality.i found one article in [SymfonyLab](http://www.symfonylab.com/extra-questions-and-solutions-for-sfguardplugin/), but was not clear enough.

Comment: Can you define custom login/logout more specifically - do you mean as in a custom template for the login page, or something different?

Comment: It's like custom Template for login page. instead of Symfonys default login, want to create a custom login page.

Comment: Do you want to change the view, perform different login/logout actions, or perform additional login/logout actions? Depending on which combination of these 3 (or other) things affects the answer.

Comment: in y application there a user page which gives user to edit his information. but it requires a login as such the user logs in then he should be redirected towards the user edit page else to the error page. I want this Login to be made custom like by template and by functionally.. i.e in the above case @jeremy "perform different login/logout actions"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Easiest way to override the view of sfGuard signin:

1) Create a directory called 'sfGuardAuth' in your frontend module:

```
mkdir apps/frontend/modules/sfGuardAuth
mkdir apps/frontend/modules/sfGuardAuth/templates
```

2) Copy the default templates from the sfGuardPlugin folder to the new module

```
cp plugins/sfGuardPlugin/modules/sfGuardAuth/templates/* apps/frontend/modules/sfGuardAuth/templates
```

3) Edit the new files to your hearts content

4) Clear cache

```
./symfony cc
```

Comment: do you know how to customize it from the backend?? like if i make a normal symfony form and submit it to my action, the controller should check the login info and create a session.

Comment: wouldn't that be reinventing the login action? You can easily override  the actions as well by extending sfGuardAuthActions in your own modules/sfGuardAuth/actions/actions.class.php - take a look at the BasesfGuardAuthActions.class.php in plugins/sfGuardPlugin/modules/sfGuardAuth/lib folder to see which actions to override.

Answer (score 2):

You can also display the login form wherever you want. I have a page for users to register or login, so I did something like:

> $this->signin = new sfGuardFormSignin();

then in the view you can do whatever you'd like.